# Assign ID that increments automatically - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently working on a ticketing system using Mongo, I've got the basics down, (making tickets, admins responding, etc) but I want to assign a unique ID to allow the user to view the ticket, so /tickets/view/(id), problem is, I don't really know how to assign one, I don't want to use the auto assigned mongo one because it just looks bad on the system, so, how would I assign a ticket with an id that goes up each ticket?

**Using: MongoDB Node Module, Express**

Comment: MongoDB automatically creates an `_id` field which is (usually) unique. What's your problem with this ID?

Comment: The ID field is normally pretty long, and I don't like displaying a long id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate `counters` collection for sequences, which will store current values.

Then on any insert -  query for current value for wanted counter and increment in single operation.

Complete tutorial on that: [MongoDB Auto-increment sequence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm)

Comment: Instead of plainly linking to examples, it will be nice to quote an example of how to declare the counters.